# How to replace the rhino scripting jar used by Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I want to use Eclipse Indigo to develop some JavaScript code. But the rhino jar used by Eclipse must be older than the most recent version and it makes problems. I want to replace it with the newest build.

Does anyone know how can I replace it?

Comment: Are you creating a java app that's picking up rhino from eclipse?  Or you are using JSDT to edit JS in eclipse and it is not evaluating correctly?

Comment: The latter is true. It hangs and crashes and I am using the Indigo version of Eclipse. I just guess it is not using the latest Rhino version. Anyway, I'd like to try the latest Rhino beta, but how?

Answer (score 1):

To replace rhino used within your eclipse by JSDT, you would have to

1. turn your rhino.jar into an OSGi bundle, similar to the org.mozilla.javascript listed on http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20120119162704/
2. Find the feature that includes the javascript jar, maybe scanning the `eclipse/features/*/feature.xml` files
3. Create a feature patch for that feature including your new version of rhino, and export
4. Install it into you eclipse

But OSGi bundles can add valid bundle version ranges to their dependencies, so you wouldn't be able to tell if it could work without trying it, or finding all bundles that depend on rhino and checking their dependency.

Comment: Sounds as a non starter to me.